Reseting Safari Bookmarks in order to fix Syncing issues
I have a Mac running macOS 12.7.6 and two iOS 18.1 devices (iPad and iPhone) and I would like to sync the bookmarks between them. I also have a Windows machine with a Firefox plugin to sync the bookmarks (I can live without this, but doesn't seem to be the cause of any breaking). This was mostly working, with the only issue being sometimes it would be slow to sync, or if I added a bookmark on two devices near the same time it would be confused and might not add them correctly (wrong order maybe or not add them until a third bookmark would force the sync).
I recently imported a large bookmarks folder (several hundred bookmarks, 2500-line long HTML backup file), and started reorganizing them all. This broke my iPad bookmarks, forking it into a different syncing state. At this point, my Mac, iPhone, and Firefox all synced correctly. I then tried the various solutions online, turning off and on the Safari iCloud sync, rebooting, deleting all bookmarks and trying to add only one bookmark, and deleting the Safari iCloud storage. When I did this step there were two, slightly differently sized (814 KB vs 868 KB or something; compared to my ~200 KB bookmark backup) I tried to delete these to force a restart but since Safari has not returned to the iCloud storage management page, even if I have the syncing turned on. Currently, all devices no longer sync at all.
Ultimately I want to fix the bookmarks, requiring resetting my broken Safari somehow, does anyone know any fix for this?
Also, iCloud tabs do work across my devices, so it must be syncing something.

I eventually was able to 'solve' this issue. By going to the iClouds recover website at https://www.icloud.com/recovery/ you can view old deleted bookmarks. This lets you recover bookmarks up to a month old. It seems the issue for me was that there was too many bookmarks in this system which was slowing down everything, resulting in probably the bookmark syncing to timeout or something.
I deleted these, there was 15000 of them, and they had to be deleted 10 at a time, so I wrote a quick autohotkey script on my pc to run overnight and just move between the delete and confirmation button with a timer while waiting for the tab to load (this was ~16s per 10 when I started, and took 7hours or so).
Now I was able to apply the normal fixes, opt out of all safari iCloud syncing on all devices and then reactivate and they all quickly fixed. Unfortunately Safari is still missing from my settings: iCloud > Manage...
